# Can someone help me out here, can't get the routing to work properly, keep getting 404

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to route the child component through the parent, so that the child component displays on the parent component when the link inside the parent is clicked.

I've tried to follow the angular routing tutorial https://angular.io/guide/router but I can't get it to work, I also tried the method on stack overflow:
[angular 4 - routing within a component(child routes) not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635377/angular-4-routing-within-a-componentchild-routes-not-working-properly)

UPDATE:

1. I've added a version on stackblitz, here's the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksfrpn
2. I've tried changing the routing e.g. { path: 'dashboard' component: DashboardComponent } to { path: "" component: DashboardComponent }, I'm able to display the dashboard, but what I want is to display the One component within the dashboard component.
3. I'm getting a 404 when I try to get to "one component", basically I'm trying to create the url path "application/home" as the base and when dashboard is clicked you get "application/dashboard" there after on the dashboard a user can click "one" and be taken to "application/dashboard/one" where the one component will display.

app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { DashboardModule } from './dashboard/dashboard.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule,
    DashboardModule,
    AppRoutingModule,


  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas:      [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from "./page-not-found/page-not-found.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: "dashboard", pathMatch: 'full' },
  { 
    path: 'dashboard', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(mod => mod.DashboardModule),
    data: {preload: true}
  },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [    RouterModule.forRoot(
    routes,
    { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
  )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

dashboard.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DashboardComponent } from "./dashboard.component";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './dashboard-routing.module';
import { OneComponent } from "./one/one.component";



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    OneComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    DashboardRoutingModule,

  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

dashboard-routing.module

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Route, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { OneComponent } from "./one/one.component";
import { DashboardComponent } from "./dashboard.component";

const dashBoardRoutes : Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'one',
        component: OneComponent
      }    
    ]

  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(dashBoardRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Links

```
<links>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a routerLink="/home">Home<span class="sr-only">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</links>
```

What I'm trying to do is to display the 'one component' within the dashboard component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove *pathMatch: 'full'* from dashBoardRoutes and it will work.

Get more details for patchMatch here: https://angular.io/api/router/Route

Comment: Thank you!! It worked, I get it now, It looks like it was routing directly to the component i.e. 'application/one', instead of 'application/dashboard/one'

Answer (score 0):

From what you included in your question, it looks like you linked to the wrong route path.
You're using Lazy Loading for the `DashboardModule`: You defined the `dashboard` route in the `AppRoutingModule` and used `loadChildren` here to lazy load the `DashboardModule`.

Then, in the `DashboardRoutingModule` you put **another** route with the path `dashboard`.
To reach this route you need to combine the prefix path from the `AppRoutingModule` (`dashboard`) plus the path from the actual route (also `dashbaord`).
The result is `dashbaord/dashboard` – please try linking to this path with your RouterLink.

If you want this path to be just `dashboard`, you need to change your route paths.
The one in the `AppRoutingModule` must remain as it is, but you can just provide an empty path for the leaf route:

```
{ path:  '', component: DashboardComponent }
```

Hope this helps! For your next question, please provide some additional information:

- What does not work? Are there any error messages?
- What have you tried with which effect?
- A minimal reproduction in a StackBlitz project would be great!

Comment: I made the changes and added the reproduction on stack blitz, unfortunately I'm getting a 404 error, when I try to go to the desired component within the dashboard. Here's the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksfrpn. I've also updated the question. Thank so much for the pointers 